# Webscraping a page: notification on update stock prices

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, notifications

**Question**

I am interested in web scraping and data analysis and I would like to develop my skills by writing a program using Python 2.7 that will monitor changes in stock prices. My goal is to be able to compare two stocks (for the time being) at certain points throughout the day, save that info into a document format easily handled by pandas (which I will learn how to use after I get this front end working). In the end I would like to map relationship trends between chosen stocks (when this one goes up by x what effect does that have on the other one). This is just a hobby project so it doesn't matter if the code is production quality.

**My Experience**

I am a brand new Python programmer (I have a very basic understanding of python and no real experience with any non-included modules) but I do have a technical background so if the answer to my question requires reading and understanding documentation intended for intermediate level programmers that should be OK.

For the basics I am working my way through Learning Python: Powerful Object-Oriented Programming by Mark Lutz if this helps any.

**What I'm Looking For**

I recognize this is a very broad subject and I am not asking for anyone to write any actual code examples or anything. I just want some direction as to where to go to get information more specific to my interests and goals.

This is actually my first post on this forum so please forgive me if this doesn't follow best practices for posting. I did search for other questions like mine and read the posting tips docs prior to writing this.

Comment: For several reasons(too board, asking for resources, not a coding question, etc.) StackOverflow is not for this type of question. Try taking a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. That being said, a quick web search on what you are trying to do will come up with books, tutorials and other resources.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to web-scrape? If you're using Python 2.7, then you'll want to look into the `urllib2`, `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` libraries. If you're using Python 3.x, then you'll want to peek at `urllib`, `urllib.request`, and `BeautifulSoup`, again. Together, these libraries should accomplish everything you're looking to do in terms of web-scraping.

If you're interested in scraping stock data, might I suggest the [`yahoo_finance`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yahoo-finance/1.1.4) package? This is a Python wrapper for the Yahoo Finance API. Whenever I've done things with stock data in the past, this module was invaluable. There's also [`googlefinance`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/googlefinance), too. It's much easier to use these already-developed wrappers to extract stock info, rather than scraping hundreds (if not thousands) of web pages to get the data you want.